# Formatting Errors in Python

Tags: python

I've never used Python and have copied some script (with permission) from someone online, so I'm not sure why the code is dropping. I'm hoping someone can understand it and put it right for me!

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join

  #First some options here.

    !RootDir     = "C:\\Users\\***\\Documents\\GoGames"
    !OutputFile  = "C:\\Users\\***\\Documents\\GoGames\\protable.csv"
    Properties  = !!['pb', 'pw', 'br', 'wr', 'dt', 'ev', 're']

    print """
      SGF Database Maker
      ==================

      Use this program to create a CSV file with sgf info.
      """

    def getInfo(filename):
      """Read out file info here and return a dictionary with all the
      properties needed."""
      result = !![]

      file = open(filename, 'r')
      data = file.read(1024)  read at most 1kb since we assume all relevant info is in the beginning
      file.close()

      for prop in Properties:
          try:
              i = data.lower().index(prop)
          except !ValueError:
              result.append((prop, ''))
              continue
          try:
              value = data![data.index('![', i)+1 : data.index(']', i)]
          except !ValueError:
              value = ''

          result.append((prop, value))

      return dict(result)


    !ProgressCounter = 0

    file = open(!OutputFile, "w")
    file.write('^Filename^;^PB^;^BR^;^PW^;^WR^;^RE^;^EV^;^DT^\n')

    for root, dirs, files in walk(!RootDir):
      for name in files:
          if name![-3:].lower() != "sgf":
              continue

          info = getInfo(join(root, name))

          file.write('^'+join(root, name)+'^;^'+info!['pb']+'^;^'+info!['br']+'^;^'+info!['pw']+'^;^'+info!['wr']+'^;^'+info!['re']+'^;^'+info!['ev']+'^;^'+info!['dt']+'^\n')
          !ProgressCounter += 1
          if (!ProgressCounter) % 100 == 0:
              print str(!ProgressCounter) + " games processed."


    file.close()

    print "A total of " + str(!ProgressCounter) + " have been processed."
```

Using Netbeans IDE I get the following error:

```
  !RootDir     = "C:\\Users\\***\\Documents\\GoGames"
  ^
SyntaxError: mismatched input '' expecting EOF
```

I have previously been able to step through the code as far as file.close(), where I go an error "does not match outer indentation level".

Anyone able to put the syntax of this code right for me?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the exclamation marks in front of variable names, list declarations (`!![]`) and in `except` clauses (`except !ValueError`), this is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: The code also needs to be cleaned up indentation and spacing wise... as well as bad naming (OP should follow PEP8 and fix that script).